# Running multiple postgres database clusters on the same server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We are currently running postgres 9.5 on rhel7 and have a one database cluster per server. I'm looking at adding multiple database clusters per host, and am wondering whether there are any recommendations for memory settings when doing this?

for example, a general rule of thumb seems to be that the `shared_buffers` should be set to 1/4 of your system memory. So my question would be do you divide the 1/4 between the N clusters on the server, or do you allocate 1/4 of the memory per cluster (therefore only have approx 3-4 clusters on each host)

thanks
dave

Comment: Allocate 1/4 of the memory per cluster rather than N cluster on server because per cluster will have more memory consumption during larger operation let the cluster's decide among themselves :D

Comment: Hi, @AshiqAhamed, so that would limit the number of clusters on the server to a max of 4 (realistically 3 due to other processes requiring some system memory)? And would this still be true for a server with say 512GB+ memory?